# How can I add rel to anchor tags & id to thumbnail in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a portfolio page. & I have to dynamically generated "id" for images[thumbnail] & "rel" for the anchor tags. so I can connect them. but I don't know how to do this.

here is my current porofolio code:

```
<div class="main-interior portfolio" id="portfolio-big-pics" style="display: block;">
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'order' => 'ASC');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
<?php $extraLastClass = $loop->current_post + 1 === $loop->post_count ? ' main-image-porfolio-main' : '';?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail( "thumbnail", array( "class" => "main-image portfolio $extraLastClass" ) ); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?> 

<?php rewind_posts(); ?> 


    <div class="portfolio-box">
        <h5>Portfolio</h5>
        <ul class="item-list" id="portfolio-list">
        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>              
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

I've also added a screenshot for better understanding.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simple use your attributes array:

```
$attributes = array(
    "class" => "main-image portfolio " . $extraLastClass,
    "rel" => "whatever rel you want",
    'id' => 'whatevere id you want',
    'whatever attribute you want' => 'whatever value for that attribute'
);
the_post_thumbnail("thumbnail", $attributes);
```

**EDIT**

If you want to add it to your link, then just simple modify:

```
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

to

```
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
```

where `$post` is your post object.

And as I see, (from your previous question) you are not looping through on the titles.

Comment: I want id to be added to the thumbnail & rel to be added to the anchor links. if I use your code. both id & rel assigned to the thumbnails. & also the id is same for all the photos. I want this id to be dynamic & unique for every image. like for image 1: photo_1, for image 2: photo_2, for image 3: photo_3

Comment: for better understanding you can visit this link: http://kzarchitecture.com/portfolio/
I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I think we are getting there. but the id is now static for every image after I added your code. I want the id & rel to be matched... like if the id is "photo_45", the rel ll be "45"!

Comment: actually I find out what I need now. my anchor tags have rel like: rel="45", rel="46", rel="47".

I need to assign this rel value to the id of my thumbnails. so after adding they ll change "photo_" to "photo_45", "photo_46","photo_47".

photo_ is my id name at this moment!

Comment: Use a PHP variable there, as in my answer. Like `rel="photo_<?php echo $myDynamicId; ?>"`

Comment: ok I solve it, but I don't know if it is a good coding or not, please confirm me `<?php 
$attributes = array(
    "class" => "main-image portfolio " . $extraLastClass,
    "id" => "photo_$post->ID",
);
the_post_thumbnail("large", $attributes);
?>`

Comment: Not. PHP wont parse the `"photo_$post->ID"` It should be `"photo_{$post->ID}"` or `"photo_" . $post->ID`

Comment: ok, I have replaced it. one last question. from my code you can see I'm targeting the last image by this code: `$extraLastClass = $loop->current_post + 1 === $loop->post_count ? ' main-image-porfolio-main' : '';` working fine, but if I want to target the first image not the last?

Comment: I gotta go now, to my mother to celebrate the christmas. So Merry Christmas for you. Plese write me at here tomorrow, and I will check.